# Apex- swagger does not show data from functions and json objects from sql query

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, swagger, apex

I want to generate swagger documentation through Apex using as handler a long sql query with nested objects and functions in it. Here is a part of query (almost 500 lines):

```
`select *
from (with branch as (select main_institution_uuid,
                             max(last_update)              last_update,
                             json_arrayagg(json_object('branchUuid' value uuid,
                                                       'branchName' value name,
                                                       'branchCity' value city)
                                           returning clob) branches
                      from INSTITUTION a
                      where kind = 'INSTITUTION_BRANCH'
                      group by institution_uuid)
      select json_object('institutionUuid' value vw.uuid,
--                          'institutionUid' value vw.table_uid,
                         'name' value vw.name,
--                          'id' value to_char(id),
                         'iKindCd' value case
                                             when vw.uuid = '7d1' 
                                                 then
                                                 null
                                             else
                                                 to_char(vw.code_kind)
                             end,
                         'iKindName' value case
                                               when vw.uuid = '7d1' then
                                                   
                                               else
                                                   vw.kind
                             end,
                         'uTypeCd' value to_char(vw.u_type_code),
                         'uTypeName' value vw.u_type_name,
                         'siTypeCd' value to_char(vw.si_type_code),
                         'siTypeName' value vw.si_type_name,
                         'status' value vw.status,
                         `
```

And this is all swagger doc what I get from my query

```
`openapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: ORDS generated API for 
  version: 1.0.0
servers:
  - url: 
paths:
  /institution:
    get:
      description: Retrieve records from 
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []
        - BearerAuth: []
        - OAuth2: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The queried record.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  items:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: object
                      properties:
                        '{}institution':
                          $ref: '#/components/schemas/CLOB'
      parameters: []
  /institution_test:
    get:
      description: Retrieve records from
      security:
        - BasicAuth: []
        - BearerAuth: []
        - OAuth2: []
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The queried record.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                type: object
                properties:
                  items:
                    type: array
                    items:
                      type: object
                      properties: {}
components:
  securitySchemes:
    BasicAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: basic
    BearerAuth:
      type: http
      scheme: bearer
    OAuth2:
      type: oauth2
      flows:
        implicit:
          authorizationUrl: 
          scopes: {}
        authorizationCode:
          authorizationUrl:
          tokenUrl: 
          scopes: {}
        clientCredentials:
          tokenUrl: 
          scopes: {}
  schemas:
    CLOB:
      type: string`
```

What can I do to make swagger create the correct document or somehow overwrite the missing data?

Comment: Aren't you re-inventing the wheel ? This should be available out of the box - documented here: https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/oracle-rest-data-services-ords-open-api-swagger-support or am I missing something ?

Comment: No, I tried to generate documentation via open api catalog (swagger in apex) and there from very long code i get only 3 lines in documentation...